# Why use util.inherits and .call for inheritance in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I am wondering why, when creating a new `stream` class in node, I need to use both `call` and `util.inherits`

For instance, in the following code, which is used to create a readable stream, I have to use both:

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var util = require('util');


var MyStream = function (options) {
    Readable.call(this, options)
}

util.inherits(MyStream, Readable); //Hasn't this already inherited all methods from Readable via "call"

var stream = new MyStream();
```

It seems to be that `Readable.call` is calling the constructor from `Readable` and therefore the `util.inherits` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`util.inherits` will merge the prototype from `Readable` into `MyStream`.  Both this prototype merge and the constructor call are required for a more complete sense of inheritance.

The constructor call `Readable.call( ... )` will just run through the constructor of `Readable`, likely initializing some variables and maybe do some initial setup.

The prototype merge `util.inherits(MyStream, Readable);` will take the prototype methods on `Readable` and stick them onto any future instances of `MyStream`.

So without the constructor call you don't get that initial setup, and without the prototype merge you don't get the methods.  From that you can see why it is required to both both steps.